# SQL Update statement using multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

I want to update a table called `Dash`, the column I want to update is called `Analysts`. From the code below I am getting a `NameLast` of a person where their `RoleId` is either 3 or 4. This code will get the first occurance of that person and insert their last name into `Analysts`, but what I want is comma separated list of last names for all `Person` with `RoleId` 3 or 4.

```
    UPDATE Dash
    SET Dash.Analysts = Person.NameLast
    FROM dbo.Dash
    INNER JOIN dbo.Item 
    ON Dash.DPItem = Item.ItemId        
    INNER JOIN dbo.Assignment 
    ON Item.ItemId = Assignment.ItemId
    INNER JOIN dbo.Person
    ON Assignment.PersonId = Person.PersonId
    WHERE (Person.RoleId = 3 or Person.RoleId = 4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update Dash set
    Analysts = 
    stuff(
         (
             select ', ' + P.NameLast
             from dbo.Item as I
                 inner join dbo.Assignment as A on A.ItemId = I.ItemId
                 inner join dbo.Person as P on P.PersonId = A.PersonId
             where I.ItemId = D.DPItem and P.RoleId in (3, 4)
             for xml path(''), type
         ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 2, '')
from dbo.Dash as D
```